# Cart session Not Found When Using Axios Post

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, post, axios

I am trying to implement cart functionality using [bumbummen99/LaravelShoppingcart](https://github.com/bumbummen99/LaravelShoppingcart) where the user can increase/decrease quantities of items in their cart. Pressing '+' or '-' fires an onclick javascript function called *updateCart()*.

*updateCart()* uses [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) to send a post request to my CartController@updateCart() where I run the logic to update the cart quantities.

> ***Problem: I lose access to the global cart session after submitting the post request.***
>
> Once I'm in updateCart() in CartController, I can access the request
>   variables from axios successfully. However, I am unable to access my
>   cart session. I can't locate the cart items even though I have the
>   correct rowId.
>
> My cart has items in it but typing Cart::content() or Cart::get() returns error 500 because it thinks my cart is empty.

As soon as I can retrieve my cart, I can implement the logic to update the quantity using Cart::update(), etc. Please help!

---

**Hitting + or - triggers updateCart(action,rowId)**

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>

<script>
    function updateCart(action,rowId) {
        axios.post('/api/update-cart', {
            action: action,
            rowId: rowId
        }).then(response => console.log(response)).catch(error => {
            console.log(error.response)
        });
    }
</script>
```

**Api.php**

```
Route::post('update-cart', 'CartController@updateCart')->name('update-cart');
```

**CartController.php**

```
public function updateCart(Request $request) {

    //works, returns '620d670d95f0419e35f9182695918c68'
    return $request->get('rowId');

    //works, returns 'add' or 'subtract'
    return $request->get('action');

    //fails, returns empty array
    return Cart::content();

    //fails, error 500 because cannot find cart instance
    return Cart::get('620d670d95f0419e35f9182695918c68');

    return 200;
}
```

When ran, I lose access to Cart::content() and related Cart functions. It's trying to return Cart::content() which should display my entire cart.
[image]

**this is when I return Cart::content() on any other page**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access sessions within API routes.

APIs are based on tokens, not sessions. Read about "JWT" (JSON Web Token) or "OAuth" or "Laravel Passport".

You can still enforce sessions if you really want to:

Open `app/Http/Kernel.php`

Find `protected $middlewareGroups =`

Where you should see `'api' => [`

Just add this:
`\App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,`

Comment: I will look into this, thanks for the insight. Do you think the Cart package I am using is implementing sessions?

Comment: @ryank Yes. https://github.com/bumbummen99/LaravelShoppingcart/blob/master/src/Cart.php#L700

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use cart in database.

Let say someone use your api with web, then he was add to cart. Next day he back to your shop but use mobile app. So if we use session, i think its can not with api. But if use database, you can store cart data base on User ID right.